# Android canvas: Cut off part of drawing

Tags: java, android, canvas

So I have a custom class called `RoundRectText` that draws text inside a `RoundRect` created from `Path.addRoundRect()`.  What I'd like to do is prevent the posibility of this happening:

[image]

I want  to prevent the text from running outside the rectangle. Is there any way I can cut off the drawing at a certain point?

The best solution I have come up with is looping through the `String` and using `Paint.measureText()` to stop drawing the rest of the `String` if it surpasses the width but I'd like to know if there is another/better way to do this.

I have also tried using `Canvas.clipRect()` but this gets rid of other things that I draw and still draws the text going out of the bounds

Comment: so should the looong text be drawn in multiline layout? or just cut off?

Comment: @pskink cut off

Comment: see `TextUtils#ellipsize`

Comment: @pskink That worked thanks